# Enforcing the implementer of an interface to be an enum

Tags: java, enums, interface

I would like to store a type called `App` inside a set. `App` needs to be an enum that implements the `App` interface.

```
Set<App> myApps;
```

I have defined the interface like so...

```
interface App<T extends Enum<T>> {}
```

This is almost working, for example, you cannot do this...

```
class MyClass implements Application<MyClass> {}
```

However, you can do this...

```
enum MyEnum implements Application<MyEnum> {}
class Myclass implements Application<MyEnum> {}
```

Which is wrong. I only want enums to be able to implement this interface, how can I enforce this?

Comment: And exactly what error-message do you get from the compiler? Please edit your post to show us, consistently, *all* of your declarations.

Comment: @MikeRobinson he doesn't get an error message, that's the problem - he wants the compiler to complain about the last declaration. ;)

Comment: @MikeRobinson read the question again. There's no error from the compiler. OP just wants to restrict the implementer.

Comment: Not a solution but at least an improvement: `interface App<T extends Enum<T> & App<T>>`. With your version you could do `class Myclass implements Application<MyEnum>` even if `MyEnum` doesn't implement `App<MyEnum>` so with the improvement you at least can prevent the dev to use _any_ enum. Besides that, is there a reason to require the implementation to be an enum? And would there be a way to at least check the `isEnum()` flag on the actual class at runtime (e.g. when passing an instance of `App` around)?

Comment: Interfaces can't describe what types they can be attached to, they simply describe some enforced (guaranteed) behaviour of the type that implements them.  What you are describing is not really a feature of the language, so you'll be hard pressed to find a way of creating the development defence mechanism you're after.

Comment: *"d'oh!"* --- Of course ... of course ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Define a method that allows you to add Elements into the set, BUT use a constraint for that parameter...

```
 public <E extends Enum<E> & IMyInterface> void addToSet(final E value) { }
```

now after that

```
addToSet(MyEnum.K) will compile
```

but

```
addToSet(new Myclass()) will NOT compile
```

Comment: So it's pretty much the same type parameter stuff except as part of a method declaration rather than an interface declaration - neat :)

Comment: What will the type of my set be?

Comment: I've not seen the architecture but I suspect you want to call the abstract methods of the interface the enumerator is implementing, therefore I would suggest to define a Set holding the interface as a DataType

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it is not possible to enforce an implementor of an interface to have certain properties such as being an enum.

However, depending on your code and how you use that interface you can make it hard for someone not to make the implementor an enum:

- Require `T` to implement `App<T>` as well to prevent passing any enum to the class declaration (i.e. `App<T extends Enum<T> & App<T>>`)
- Use additional boundaries when possible (see ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa's answer)
- Add methods that are already implemented by `Enum` such as `name()`, `ordinal()`, `getDeclaringClass()` etc.
- Let `App<T ...>` extend `Comparable<T>`.
- When possible call `getClass().isEnum()` to check that property at runtime. This is not ideal but there are similar solution's that are commonly used such as `Collections.unmodifiableSet()`.